# Why it is not printing maximum and minimum value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

It give error "bad input on line 13."

Problem statement: "Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below."

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
      num = input("Enter a number: ")
      if num == "done" : break
      try:
           num=int(num)
      except:
           print("Invalid input")
           continue
      if smallest is None:
            smallest=num
      elif num < smallest:
            smallest=num

      if largest is None:
            largest=num
      elif num > largest:
            largest=num
print("Maximum is",largest)
print("Minimum is",smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 7, you don't have `num=int(num)` indented for the try statement. When I indented that, it ran for me.

Comment: umm! that was a typing mistake here. I've corrected it but the problem persists.